# SQL Subquery In Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM StocksFinancial

IN

(SELECT *
FROM Stocks
WHERE Market_Cap <= 13);
```

Above is the SQL code that I'm trying to write for a query that should show the financial information of the stock that has a market cap of less than 13. However, I am getting a

> Syntax error FROM clause.

I am using Access 2007.

I am new to SQL.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't hang together syntactically:

You'd have to do something more like

```
 SELECT * FROM StocksFinancial
   WHERE stock_id IN 
         (
             SELECT stock_id 
               FROM Stocks
              WHERE market_cap <= 13
         )
```

The query inside the IN expression must return only one column.

Comment: Thanks that worked liked a charm. I modified it a bit...

SELECT * FROM StocksFinancial
   WHERE Company_Name IN 
         (
             SELECT Company_Name 
               FROM Stocks
              WHERE market_cap <= 13
         );

Answer (score 0):

To use `in` you need a `where` clause.  Your query as written doesn't make sense.  It should be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM StocksFinancial sf
where sf.stockname IN (SELECT stockname FROM Stocks WHERE Market_Cap<=13);
```